# Comparing observer_ptr< T > with T *

Tags: c++, c++17

As far as I can see, the `observer_ptr` proposal includes (in)equality comparisons with `nullptr_t` and cross-type (i.e., `observer_ptr< T >` vs. `observer_ptr<U>`) comparisons. There is no comparison with raw pointers, which is a bit of an annoyance when trying to gradually introduce it into an existing code base.

**Question 1**: Do you foresee any serious issues if I add these operators (I am using a separate implementation of `observer_ptr` in a different namespace, modeled exactly on the current proposal, I will not be adding these to the `std::observer_ptr`)?

**Follow-up**: If adding the operators is a bad idea, would it be better to use get() on the `observer_ptr` to compare against the raw pointer, or would it be better to wrap the raw pointer explicitly as a `observer_ptr` ?

Edit: Apparently it's not clear enough - I want to know why `observer_ptr<T>` is missing these comparison operators. If it's simply an omission, I can add them to my implementation and be on my merry way. If there is a reason behind that choice, I would like to understand what it is, and whether I care enough to avoid adding these operators to my class.

Comment: I suspect only Walter Brown can answer your question.

Comment: @ildjarn That may be so, but it seems at least a line or two in the proposal could have discussed this; unless a discussion is buried somewhere in a very early draft (I found a discussion about adding implicit conversion to T* which would obviously solve this, but it disappeared later)

Answer (score 1):

Write a standalone template function that compares `observer_ptr<T>` with `T*` and use it everywhere in your project. Then you can change implementation later if necessary using `.get()` or ctor or something else.

Comment: That's my inclination, but I want to know why observer_ptr does not already specify this - presumably there's a reason for that and I want to know what could go wrong if I do that. It may also turn out that it's just an omission, but if so, it seems to be a glaring one.

On second read - why would I do this to myself. There already is a function named 'operator==' that is used like a million times in the code base already. I think the question is clear enough and I'm not looking for extra ideas, I'm looking to understand observer_ptr' design.